# Filter on user id

Tags: angularjs

I have join table that creates an association between my movie and user table. If I use,

```
"ng-repeat" => "movie in movies"
```

I get all the movies added by all the users. So I'm trying to filter out all the results that do not correspond with the users id.

This is the JSON result of my `movies_users` request,

```
{"id":4,
  "title":"Creed",
  "release_date":"2016-01-21",
  "image":"/xSE4NBFDzqedwa4AIj99r1Z7ljF.jpg",
  "user_id":null,
  "created_at":"2015-11-14T12:07:43.434Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-11-14T12:07:43.434Z",
  "movie_id":"312221",
  "users":[
    {"id":2,"email":"jan@jan.com","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":"Jan Jansen","username":null},
    {"id":1,"email":"peter@peter.nl","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":"Peter Boomsma","username":null}]
},

{"id":5,
  "title":"Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
  "release_date":"2015-12-17",
  "image":"/fYzpM9GmpBlIC893fNjoWCwE24H.jpg",
  "user_id":null,
  "created_at":"2015-11-14T12:13:40.413Z",
  "updated_at":"2015-11-14T12:13:40.413Z",
  "movie_id":"140607",
  "users":[
    {"id":1,"email":"peter@peter.nl","provider":null,"uid":null,"name":"Peter Boomsma","username":null}]
}
```

As you can see the movies have the associated users in them, but I'm wondering how I can only show the movies that also have the users id in the view.

I had this,

```
.movie_container{
  "ng-if" => "movie.user_id == user_id", 
  "ng-repeat" => "movie in movies | orderBy:'release_date'"
 }
```

But now I've changed my database/back-end it doesn't work anymore.

**EDIT**

loadMovies function

```
   movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
      $scope.movies = response.data;

      $scope.checkUserExists = function(movie_users) {
        for(var i = 0; i < movie_users.length; i++) {
            if(movie_users[i].id === movie.user.id) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
      }

    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function which will be called inside the `ng-if` directive and pass the movie iterable's users array to it:

```
ng-if="checkUserExists(movie.users)"
```

Now, define the function in your controller:

```
$scope.checkUserExists(movie_users) {
    for(var i = 0; i < movie_users.length; i++) {
        if(movie_users[i].id === user_id) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried to add your function inside my loadMovies function (see edit in question) but I'm getting a `ReferenceError: user_id is not defined` error.

Comment: I just user_id for example. Use the current user's user_id (where is it stored?)

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'current user'. Where are his details along with his id?

Comment: Sorry I had tunnel vision. I already have a method to store the current users id. I used that with your function and it seems its working. So thanks for that!

Comment: I do wonder though if it's not better to do this the other way around. Now I ask for all the movies and filter out everything that does not correspond to the current user. But wouldn't it be better to go straight to the user and show all the movies in his account?

Comment: I am not entirely sure about your app's functionality, but the way I see it, I would actually send the user id to the web api and retrieve data specific only to that user. But again, I don't know the big picture so...

Comment: Alright looks like I need to do some digging! Thanks for all the help.